# R - Add column to data.table from a calculation over a relative subset

Tags: r, data.table

I'm wanting to add a column to a data table that is a calculation of values from other columns and haven't yet been able to find a way to do it.

```
DT <- data.table("userId" = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", "user2", "user2", "user2", "user2"),
                 "topicId" = "topic1",
                 "attempt" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 "score" = c(50, 0, 50, 20, 20, 100, 100, 100, 100))

   userId topicId attempt score
1:  user1  topic1       1    50
2:  user1  topic1       2     0
3:  user1  topic1       3    50
4:  user1  topic1       4    20
5:  user2  topic1       1    20
6:  user2  topic1       2   100
7:  user2  topic1       3   100
8:  user2  topic1       4   100
9:  user2  topic1       5   100
```

Ultimately I'm wanting to add the following two columns to show the difference in scores within each user/topic group from their first attempt and their previous attempt:

```
   userId topicId attempt score scoreDiffFromFirst scoreDiffFromPrev
1:  user1  topic1       1    50                 NA                NA
2:  user1  topic1       2     0                -50               -50
3:  user1  topic1       3    50                  0                50
4:  user1  topic1       4    20                -30               -30
5:  user2  topic1       1    20                 NA                NA
6:  user2  topic1       2   100                 80                80
7:  user2  topic1       3   100                 80                 0
8:  user2  topic1       4   100                 80                 0
9:  user2  topic1       5   100                 80                 0
```

I have tried the following:

```
for(i in 2:max(DT$attempt)) {
  DT[attempt == i, scoreDiffFromFirst := score - DT[attempt == 1 & userId == userId & topicId == topicId, score]]
  DT[attempt == i, scoreDiffFromPrev := score - DT[attempt == i - 1 & userId == userId & topicId == topicId, score]]
}
```

which works until it hits an attempt number that isn't represented in every user/topic group.  This means the last row is incorrect, as highlighted below, because user1 does not have a 5th attempt:

```
   userId topicId attempt score scoreDiffFromFirst scoreDiffFromPrev
1:  user1  topic1       1    50                 NA                NA
2:  user1  topic1       2     0                -50               -50
3:  user1  topic1       3    50                  0                50
4:  user1  topic1       4    20                -30               -30
5:  user2  topic1       1    20                 NA                NA
6:  user2  topic1       2   100                 80                80
7:  user2  topic1       3   100                 80                 0
8:  user2  topic1       4   100                 80                 0
9:  user2  topic1       5   100                 50**              80**
```

Happy to learn from any suggestions, but ideally I'd love for some variation of the above to work as the speed benefits are extreme.

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: Apologies - you're correct - is fixed.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic for the last row (50, 80)?

Comment: @docendodiscimus This is the row that is incorrect - will make that clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `by=`

```
DT[order(attempt), c("scoreDiffFromFirst", "scoreDiffFromPrev") := 
  .(replace(score, 1, NA) - first(score), score - shift(score))
, by=.(userId,topicId)]

# or
DT[order(attempt), `:=`(
  scoreDiffFromFirst = replace(score, 1, NA) - first(score), 
  scoreDiffFromPrev = score - shift(score)
), by=.(userId,topicId)]
```

which gives

```
   userId topicId attempt score scoreDiffFromFirst scoreDiffFromPrev
1:  user1  topic1       1    50                 NA                NA
2:  user1  topic1       2     0                -50               -50
3:  user1  topic1       3    50                  0                50
4:  user1  topic1       4    20                -30               -30
5:  user2  topic1       1    20                 NA                NA
6:  user2  topic1       2   100                 80                80
7:  user2  topic1       3   100                 80                 0
8:  user2  topic1       4   100                 80                 0
9:  user2  topic1       5   100                 80                 0
```

For intuition behind the syntax, you can review the materials mentioned in the startup messages when the package is loaded:

> ```
> library(data.table)
> ```
>
> data.table 1.10.4.3
>
> The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
>
> Documentation: `?data.table`, `example(data.table)` and `browseVignettes("data.table")`
>
> Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com

Comment: Thanks!  However this assumes that the DT is ordered by userId/topicId/attempt.  Is there a way to make it order agnostic?

Comment: @Serenthia I've edited in `order(attempt)`, which I think addresses it..? This will just use the order temporarily to create the columns with `:=` but will preserve whatever order you had before that.

Comment: Thanks, this is ideal.  Benchmarking shows no real difference between the two, so I'll go with the second for clear indication of the assignation to each column.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` makes this easy. `first` and `lag` easily get the values of score at relative positions, while `group_by` groups the rows by `userId` and `topicId` and then applies the analysis by group, not by the table at large.

```
DT <- DT %>%
    group_by(userId, topicId) %>%
    mutate(scoreDiffFromFirst = score - first(score),
           scoreDIffFromPrev = score - lag(score))

DT
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   userId, topicId [2]
  userId topicId attempt score scoreDiffFromFirst scoreDIffFromPrev
  <fct>  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>
1 user1  topic1       1.   50.                 0.               NA 
2 user1  topic1       2.    0.               -50.              -50.
3 user1  topic1       3.   50.                 0.               50.
4 user1  topic1       4.   20.               -30.              -30.
5 user2  topic1       1.   20.                 0.               NA 
6 user2  topic1       2.  100.                80.               80.
7 user2  topic1       3.  100.                80.                0.
8 user2  topic1       4.  100.                80.                0.
9 user2  topic1       5.  100.                80.                0.
```

The one difference is that `scoreDiffFromFirst` is `0`, not `NA` on first attempt rows. If that's not what you want, you can just replace them:

```
DT[DT$attempt == 1, "scoreDiffFromFirst"] <- NA
```

Comment: I'm still getting used to `dplyr` and this is really helpful as a working example, thank you.  However, the `data.table` example runs a little faster, so I'll use that instead for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `ifelse` approach.

```
DT[, `:=`(
  scoreDiffFromFirst = ifelse(rowid(topicId) == 1, NA, score - first(score)), 
  scoreDiffFromPrev = c(NA, diff(score))), by = userId]
```